# Ayuda ejercicios Funciones y procedimientos en C

Tags: c, funciones

necesitaria ayuda en un ejercicio de funciones y procedimientos en C. Paso a dejar la consigna: 
Crear una funcion y devolver 0 si es falso y 1 si es verdadero y probarlo en el main con casos positivos y negativos. 
Ejercicio a realizar: intSonIguales(char nombre1[20], char nombre2[20]);

Paso a dejar el código que pude realizar pero el cual no entiendo por que falla. El error me lo marca en la linea 22 dentro del main, "too few argument to function 'sonIguales'"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#define SALTO "\n\n------------------------------------\n\n"

//FUNCIONES
int sonIguales(char nombre1[20], char nombre2[20]);
//PROCEDIMIENTOS
void saltoDeLinea();



 int main()
    {

   printf("1=VERDADERO | 0=FALSO\n\n");


   saltoDeLinea();

   int nombresComparados = sonIguales(char nombre1[20], char nombre2[20]);

   printf("¿EL NOMBRE1 ES IGUAL A NOMBRE2?\n");
   printf("%d", nombresComparados);

   return 0;
  }


  int sonIguales(char nombre1[20], char nombre2[20]){

  char verdadero = 1;
  char falso = 0;

  printf("Ingrese el nombre 1: \n");
  fflush(stdin);
  scanf("%s", nombre1);
  printf("Ingrese el nombre 2: \n");
  fflush(stdin);
  scanf("%s", nombre2);

  int resComparacion = strcmp(nombre1, nombre2);

  return resComparacion;
  }

  void saltoDeLinea(){

  printf(SALTO);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Mirando el código tengo 2 observaciones

1. Dentro del main, estas declarando los atributos de la función y no los parámetros para que trabaje con ellos.

`int nombresComparados = sonIguales(char nombre1[20], char nombre2[20]);`

tendría que quedar así :

```
int nombresComparados = sonIguales(nombre1, nombre2);
```

2. Investiga que hace la funcion strcmp ya que lo que regresa es un 0 cuando son iguales o un numero positivo cuando la primer palabra es mayor o un numero negativo cuando la segunda palabra es mayor a la primera.

Answer (score 1):

Asi creo que sin modificar tanto tu codigo es como deberia funcionar

```
int main(){
  char nombre1[20];
  char nombre2[20];
  printf("1=VERDADERO | 0=FALSO\n\n");
  printf(SALTO);

  printf("Ingrese el nombre 1: \n");
  fflush(stdin);
  scanf("%s", nombre1);
  printf("Ingrese el nombre 2: \n");
  fflush(stdin);
  scanf("%s", nombre2);

  int nombresComparados = sonIguales(nombre1, nombre2);

  printf("¿EL NOMBRE1 ES IGUAL A NOMBRE2?\n");
  printf("%d", nombresComparados);

  return 0;
}


int sonIguales(char nombre1[20], char nombre2[20]){

   int resComparacion = strcmp(nombre1, nombre2);
   if(resComparacion = 0){
       return 1;
   }
   else{
       return 0;
   }
}
```

PD: No tengo IDE para C instalado por lo que no lo puedo ejecutar para comprobar, espero que sea util